# Driving from London to Malaga, Spain. Tolls expensive?

Tags: london, driving, spain, tolls

I've been waiting a long time to get a car, and now that I have one I plan to do a road trip with friends and visit my parents who live in southern Spain.

I'm aware of the costs to get to Santander but what of the toll roads. What can I expect to pay in tolls driving from Santander to Malaga?

Also, if taking the ferry is not the cheapest method of getting to Spain, what is the cheapest way to drive from London to Malaga?

Comment: Getting out of London to Spain, without a ferry? (Tongue-in-cheek)

Comment: No problem, there is the Eurostar (www.eurostar.com)

Comment: @RoflcoptrException Indeed! Never realised that Britain no longer is an island.

Comment: For the French part: [How do you avoid the hefty toll fee on the French highways?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/8912/how-do-you-avoid-the-hefty-toll-fee-on-the-french-highways)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

According to [Viamichelin](http://www.viamichelin.co.uk) there are no toll costs on driving from [Santander to Malaga](http://www.viamichelin.co.uk/web/Itineraires?strStartLocid=31NDEzdzgxMGNORE11TkRZd09UWT1jTFRNdU9EQTNPVE09&strDestLocid=31M3k4dzEwY016WXVOekU1TmpjPWNMVFF1TkRJd01EUT0=&intItineraryType=1&caravaneHidden=false&vh=CAR&strVehicle=0&itineraryCarType=0&itineraryFuelType=0&isFavoriseAutoroute=false&isAvoidPeage=false&isAvoidVignette=false&isAvoidLNR=false&isAvoidFrontiers=false&dtmDeparture=23/11/2012&distance=mi&devise=0.6756757%7CGBP&indemnite=&carbCost=1.6&autoConso=6.8&villeConso=6&routeConso=5.6). You would spend about 50 GBP on Tolls if you were to drive all the way from [London](http://www.viamichelin.co.uk/web/Itineraires?strStartLocid=31NDFhcWsxMGNOVEV1TlRBd01qUT1jTFRBdU1USTNNRFk9&strDestLocid=31M3k4dzEwY016WXVOekU1TmpjPWNMVFF1TkRJd01EUT0=&intItineraryType=1&caravaneHidden=false&vh=CAR&strVehicle=0&itineraryCarType=0&itineraryFuelType=0&isFavoriseAutoroute=false&isAvoidPeage=false&isAvoidVignette=false&isAvoidLNR=false&isAvoidFrontiers=false&dtmDeparture=23/11/2012&distance=mi&devise=0.6756757%7CGBP&indemnite=&carbCost=1.6&autoConso=6.8&villeConso=6&routeConso=5.6).

Comment: Wow. Thanks for suggesting that site. Will definitely come in handy