# Toll road cost for car ride from Marseille to Perpignan

Tags: france, tolls

I can't seem to find a reliable source for this information.  We will soon be travelling to France and make the journey from Marseille to Perpignan by car.  We're trying to decide whether taking the toll roads (A7-A54-A9) would be cost effective.  How much should this itinerary cost in tolls?

Comment: Out of curiosity, how do you judge the cost effectiveness of using a toll road?  Is it the cost of the toll weighed against the time saved (as I would probably do)?  Do you take other factors into consideration?

Comment: @phoog yea time saved vs cost mostly.  The more rural roads will be better for sight-seeing though so that weighs in a bit too

Comment: Have you checked the trains instead?

Comment: As a side note, toll roads are better in some other ways too. They have gas stations, picnic areas, toilets etc. right next to the highway, distributed more or less evenly along the way, and most are open 7 days a week. Finding a toilet along a rural road can be a challenge, especially on a Sunday. Rural roads are less safe to drive as well.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The best way to calculate toll pricing in France is to use [ViaMichelin](https://www.viamichelin.com/) (not affiliated)

Putting in Marseille to Perpignan will give you a summary like this

[image: summary]

And you can find the cost section with the toll pricing (the whole price is an estimation of gas consumption at the gas price you enter on th search bar + tolls)

Comment: I'm Positively surprised even unusual fuel types such as H₂ can be selected in that search engine!

Comment: Does the cost estimate change with the changing prices of gasoline (or other fuels) on a regular basis or is gas a some fixed price based on some proprietary decision?

Comment: @FreeMan You can adjust the price of gas yourself in two clicks. Checking today, it seems a bit low but not by much, possibly just lagging a little. The secret sauce, if there is any, is in the gas mileage, the default estimate is for a broad category of cars but you can also select a make and model presumably to get a more precise estimate. As far as I can tell, you cannot extract or adjust this data.

Comment: Interesting, thanks, @Relaxed. Of course, this is _perfect_ for the OP who is simply looking for the toll charges.

Comment: There is a "loophole" in the pricing of the tolls. They are not distance-based but defined by a entrance-exit matrix instead. Sometimes exiting at a intermediate stop and then getting back at same exit shaves off some toll price. see this answer for details: https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/8918/29597